# MacBook stuck on black loading screen

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup

Today my MacBook Pro 2013 crashed so I hard reset it.

Since then it boots to a black loading screen with the Apple logo and a loading bar in the middle. The loading bar progresses to around 60% then stops.

I can't boot into recovery or safe mode and I've tried the usual troubleshooting steps to no avail.

I'm at a loss because I can't even boot to internet recovery (it loads initially but then restarts).

Do you have any advice on what I can try next?

Edit: I'm not sure if this is related but the display also stopped working, I can only see the loading bar by plugging in an external monitor through the HDMI port.

Edit 2: I can boot into single user mode run `fsck -yf` but this reports that Macintosh HD is OK

Answer (score 1):

When you don't get to a blue screen in the boot process, you can assume an OS reinstall should fix it. Your fsck results reinforce that as next step.

I would boot to Internet recovery and download the OS installer of choice if your Mac supports that.

- https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22136

When that is done, next is

- https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21900

That article has the reinstall steps linked at the bottom.